# how to sync() method additional pivot table Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

i have pivot table call **user_privilege**,

```
user_id,
privilege_id
house_group_id,
```

i use method **sync** for store data into pivot tabl, this is my method

```
  $data = $this->getCollectedData($getListCollectData, $viewType, $data);

 


    $getData = $this->crud->store($data);

    
  
    $getData->getPrivilege()->sync([
        'user_id' => $getData->id,
        'house_group_id' => $this->request->get('house_group_id'),
        'privilege_id' => 3,
    ]);
```

this is my getPrivilege() method in Users Model

```
   public function getPrivilege()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany(Privilege::class, 'user_privilege', 'user_id', 'privilege_id', 'house_group_id');
}
```

but when i click submit, return error like this

```
SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'house_group_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into `user_privilege` (`privilege_id`, `user_id`) values (b3f08343-a8f6-4a45-b7bc-b396125634d3, ?))
```

when i `dd($this->request->get('house_group_id'))` return **ID** house_group_id like this

```
"2539d741-1526-4c42-b57a-da60e2e862d8"
```

this is UUID from **house_group_id**,

Whats wrong in My Code, how to save data with addtional pivot table ?
thanks

Comment: Maybe house_group_id  is not fillable?

Comment: i am not sure.. but you can try `$getData->getPrivilege()->sync(['user_id' => $getData->id],['house_group_id' => $this->request->get('house_group_id')],['privilege_id' => 3]);`

Comment: @RobbinBenard no, pivot table not have Model

Comment: @noor i already try your code, but still error same like above

Comment: what is the name of you pivot table `user_privilege` or `user_privileges` ? please  check in db

Comment: another try.. replace `sync` with `attach`...  i have done with `attach` function something like this...also chek [link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#inserting-many-to-many-relationships) from laravel doc

Comment: @noor user_privilege

Comment: @noor when i try with attach, error data truncated for privilege_id

Comment: check `privilege_id ` column type and length in db...

Comment: @noor volume type is bigInt

Comment: what error now you getting ?

Comment: @noor error data truncated for privilege_id

Comment: In databases and computer networking data truncation occurs when data or a data stream is stored in a location too short to hold its entire length. Data truncation may occur automatically, such as when a long string is written to a smaller buffer, or deliberately, when only a portion of the data is wanted..